# Flutter dependent dropdowns : Failed assertion ,when selecting value from second dropdown

Tags: android, flutter, dropdown, flutter-dependencies, mobile-application

I have two dropdown. I am getting data for both from apis. First is working fine but when Iselect the value from second it gives me below error .Second one's data is dependent on first selection.
I am getting this error
[image]

Here is my code :

```
 List<RResult> _secondList = [];
  List<RResult> _List = [];
  ResellerorSubraResult firstValue;
  ResellerorSubraResult _secondValue ;
  
  
  getReseller(BuildContext context, RResult result,
      String _type) async {
    var response = await getRequest(context, _type,
        result.id 
        );
    if (response != null) {
      if (response.success) {
        _setState(() {
          _secondList = response.result.toSet().toList();
          firstValue = result;
          uType = type;
        });
           } else {
        _secondList.clear();
        _secondList = [];
      }
    } else {
      errorRaisedToast(context);
    }
  }

                    DropdownWidget(
                            hint: 'First',
                            isExpanded: true,
                            autoValidate: false,
                            dropdownValue: firstValue,
                            dropDownList:
                                null != _List ? _List.toList() : [],
                            onChanged: (name) {
                             secondValue= null;
                              _secondList .clear();
                              _secondList = [];
                              getReseller(context, name, "uType");
                              setFilterDate();
                            },
                          )
                        : Container(),
                    VerticalSpacing(5.0),
                   DropdownWidget(
                            hint: 'Second',
                            isExpanded: true,
                            autoValidate: false,
                            dropdownValue: secondValue,
                            dropDownList: null != _secondList
                                ? _secondList.toList()
                                : [],
                            onChanged: (name) {
                              _setState(() {
                                _secondValue = name;
                                uType = "uType";
                              });
                              setFilterDate();
                            },
                          )
                        : Container(),
```

My response looks like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "total_records": 1,
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "61",
            "name": "Reseller 55"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you include your response data from dropdown button

Comment: I have edited the quetion @YeasinSheikh

Comment: You can try with using nullable data for `value` and assigning `null` it while reset

Comment: I am already doing so , making it null before calling second api

Comment: Can you try with `ResellerorSubraResult _secondValue ;` to `ResellerorSubraResult? _secondValue ;` , same goes for next one and I am not aware of `ResellerorSubraResult`

Comment: My project does not support non-null but I tried with intializong both to null , not working anyway ResellerorSubraResult _secondValue= null;
  ResellerorSubraResult firstVal = null ;

Comment: oh, This error occurs only when we don't provide unique value to the `DropdownMenuItem` and when `DropdownButton` 's value is not present on `DropdownMenuItem`'s value.

Comment: yes I read, I am trying to make sure the value null and list empty before setting new value but still error is coming some how

Comment: Then you may focus on all value and match with dropdown